# NOT NULL constraint failed when running `migrate`

Tags: django, django-migrations

I changed my models.py file and when running `migrate` I get this error. The property is a OneToOneField(). I have tried adding `null=True` but that doesn't seem to fix it. It is also weird that even when I comment out the property and run `makemigrations` followed by `migrate`, I still get that exact same error. Is there a way to fix this? My model looks like this:

```
class Estimator(Employee):
    avg_estimate = models.IntegerField()


class Job(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    estimator = models.OneToOneField(Estimator, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question.

Comment: I think you have to delete the column and again add it by adding Null condition

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that you have created a migration without null=True, that won't migrate, then you created a second migration with null=True.

Running "migrate" will run both migrations in order, so the first one will fail again.

Assuming this is the case, then 
1: delete the two most recent files in your migrations folder. (Open them first to confirm that they are creating the migrations as I described before deleting them). 
2: run makemigrations again, with null=True in your models.py

This should create the equivalent of the second migration file, without the failing intermediate migration.

Comment: Had the same problem myself recently